# how to know witch button of three buttons is clicked full solution please android studio

Tags: android

i have MainActivity and Main2Activity and Main3Activity in my project now in MainActivity i have three buttons like this:

```js
package com.example.mrj.ewacalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMain2Activity();

            }
        });
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMain2Activity();

            }
        });
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                openMain2Activity();
                }
        });
    }
    public void openMain2Activity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and in Main2Activity i have 5 buttons likie this "i put only one to try"

```js
package com.example.mrj.ewacalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {


                }

           });

        }



    public void openMain3Activity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

what i want is in MainActivity After Clicking button 1 it will open Main2Activity and in this after clicking button 1 its open say Main3Activity and if in MainActivity Clicked button 1 and Main2Activity Clicked button 2 its open say Main4Activity ..... so MainActivity button 2 and Main2Activity button 1 is something deffrent i tried intent put can't do it properly

thank you all

this will help

```js
Button1>button1=main3activity
Button1>bitton2=main4activity
Button1>button3=main5activity
Button2>button1=main6activity
Button2>button2=main7activity
Button2>button3=main8activity
Button3>button1=main9activity
Button3>button2=main9activity
Button3>button3=main10activity
```

Comment: Do you have 10 activities which are all the same? wouldn't it be better if you just press the buttons and keep track of which button you pressed all in the same activity?

try to better explain the problem because is not clear at all

Comment: Yes i have 10 activity and in my question there is what i need exactly i want if customer pressed button one in mainactivity and pressed button one in main2activity app transfer him to main3activity so i want to know how from main2activity that in mainactivity button one is pressed in full steps please and so on if button1 pressed in mainactivity and button2 is pressed in main2activity app transfer him to main4activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you revisit your design, I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but it doesn't look like the best way to do it.

Anyways, you can pass arguments to another Activity like this. Let's say user clicks on button 2 and button 3.

Main1Activity:

```
//button1 onClick
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("firstPressedButton", 2); //Your first button pressed
        intent.putExtras(b); 
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Main2Activity:

```
int firstPressedButton = -1;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //init activity

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(b != null)
            firstPressedButton = b.getInt("firstPressedButton");
}

//button3 onClick, do similar for other buttons
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(firstPressedButton == 1){
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main6Activity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(firstPressedButton == 2){
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main7Activity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(firstPressedButton == 3){
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main8Activity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks now it is working but i changed from Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main6Activity.class); to Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main6Activity.class);